# Error: Reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.0 not found

Tags: .net, visual-studio, frameworks

I am getting the following error when trying to build my project:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       MSB3644 The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.0 were not found. To resolve this problem, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this version of the framework or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks   PrintDataGridApp    C:\Projects\PrintDataGridApp\PrintDataGridApp.csproj    12
I am using Visual Studio 2022 and .NET Framework 4.8.

How can I solve that error?

I tried searching for something on the internet but I wasn't able to solve it